# Why the Node.js interface 'OutgoingHttpHeaders' does not include "content-type" header?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

The types for the Node.js module `http` includes an interface called `OutgoingHttpHeaders` that extends a generic dictionary of the type `OutgoingHttpHeader`. It list a lot of standard headers like 'accept', 'age', 'authorization', 'origin', 'referer', etc. But it does not include the header 'content-type', so it is not auto-completed while coding.

List of all predefined headers considered:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/58a1079cd07c8981027f476ebaf35a1793ef6f5e/types/node/http.d.ts#L116C11-L116C11

It is very rare since this header is included on the interface `IncomingHttpHeaders`.

Any hypothesis of why this happen?

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "plain/text" });
//                          ^ This is not autocompleted
});
```